# Lua - how to sort a table by the value chain

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table, chain

I'm looking for a method of sorting a Lua table by its values chain. Say, the table:

```
local vals = {
{ id = "checkpoint4" },
{ id = "checkpoint1", nextid = "checkpoint2" },
{ id = "checkpoint3", nextid = "checkpoint4" },
{ id = "checkpoint2", nextid = "checkpoint3" },
}
```

Should transform into this after sorting:

```
local vals = {
{ id = "checkpoint1", nextid = "checkpoint2" },
{ id = "checkpoint2", nextid = "checkpoint3" },
{ id = "checkpoint3", nextid = "checkpoint4" },
{ id = "checkpoint4" },
}
```

It's not essentially with the exact same names, they might vary. I wanted to make the comparison of numbers after "checkpoint", but it turned out that I have to work with dynamic things like this (already sorted the way I want it to be):

```
local vals = {
{ id = "checkpoint1", nextid = "cp" },
{ id = "cp", nextid = "chp" },
{ id = "chp", nextid = "mynextcheckpoint" },
{ id = "mynextcheckpoint"},
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is called [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). However, since this is a restricted case, we do not have to implement a complete topological sorting algorithm:

```
function sort_list(tbl)
  local preceding = {}
  local ending
  local sorted = {}
  for i, e in ipairs(tbl) do
    if e.nextid == nil then
      ending = e
    else
      preceding[e.nextid] = i
    end
  end
  if ending == nil then
    return nil, "no ending"
  end
  local j = #tbl
  while ending ~= nil do
    sorted[j] = ending
    ending = tbl[preceding[ending.id]]
    j = j - 1
  end
  if sorted[1] == nil then
    return nil, "incomplete list"
  end
  return sorted
end
```

Usage:

```
local sorted = sort_list(vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local id2val, tailsizes = {}, {}
for _, val in ipairs(vals) do id2val[val.id] = val end

local function tailsize(val)  -- memoized calculation of tails sizes
   if not tailsizes[val] then
      tailsizes[val] = 0                         -- cycle-proof
      if val.nextid and id2val[val.nextid] then  -- dangling nextid proof
         tailsizes[val] = tailsize(id2val[val.nextid]) + 1
      end
   end
   return tailsizes[val]
end

-- sorting according to tails sizes
table.sort(vals, function(a,b) return tailsize(a) > tailsize(b) end)
```